# Transparency with custom shader

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to control transparency (of parts of a mesh) with a fragment shader.

As a first test, I tried to adapt the [deformable sphere example](https://app.gazebosim.org/iche033/fuel/models/deformable_sphere_no_shadows) by changing the alpha value in `deform_fs.glsl`:

i.e. change

```
fragColor = vec4(finalColor, 1);
```

into

```
fragColor = vec4(finalColor, 0.5);
```

But it remains opaque.

Defining another visual in the sdf without shaders but with element `<transparency>0.5</transparency>` does yield a transparent object. Adding the `<transparency>` element to the visual with the shaders has no effect.

Is there a way to do this in the fragment shader?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29041/transparency-with-custom-shader/) by [jrtg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/156210/jrtg/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2023-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The answer is [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-rendering/issues/846)

---

Originally posted by [jrtg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/156210/jrtg/) with karma: 31 on 2023-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0